# Angular-oauth2-oidc login flow in new tab

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm using angular-oauth2-oidc to implement authorization code flow in an angular and its simple . but what I want when I click on the login button >>> open the login flow in new tab (not in the same tab) and keep the current page as it is  . is this available in oauth2-oidc services

Answer (score 0):

While it is likely technically possible, nothing is built into the library at all to handle it. So you'd be customizing usage of that library to the absolute max, and I'd recommend doing against that unless you're up for a challenge.

Possibly other libraries for OIDC and OAuth2 will better serve this purpose.